# Download manager with support of password protected sites and Content-Disposition: attachment

Tags: attachments, download-manager, password-protection

I've already tried almost 10 most rated download managers and browsers (including latest Chrome and Dolphin) to download content from a password protected site. Neither one works.

The site serves the content for download via `file.php` script (via GET request), which returns http header `Content-Disposition: attachment;`. It seems such scenario is not supported by popular Android apps.

Could someone suggest a download manager which supports such a thing?

Thanks in advance.

**Appendix A**

According to this blog post [Android and the HTTP download file headers](http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/):

> *"Another defect of the Android Download Manager is its inability to
>   handle basic authentication. If you use authentication to control
>   access to your download script, your downloads will fail with all
>   browsers that make use of the ADM (e.g. Android stock browser and
>   Dolphin)."*

AFAIK, many others do use it as well, including Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried Boat Browser? Maxthon?

Comment: @geffchang Tried both. No success.

Comment: Close voters: While this question has language which requests an app, there is a very well-defined problem to be solved. This question is fine for this site.

Comment: @Stan: Some people are a little overzealous with our "no app recommendations" rule. This may be helpful: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a product?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1289)

Comment: The download manager is something that is lacking very badly, the standalone version as supplied is pretty poor, so I think this should be left alone until Google somewhat puts out a more updated version of download manager on the play store.